# Using ESQL-Sonar plugin in IIB V10

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am trying to use the Sonar-ESQL plugin in IIB V10 for ESQL code scanning. I downloaded the plugin jar file from the website http://www.sonarplugins.com/esql, then added the jar file in the plugin folder for Eclipse and restarted Eclipse. But I dont see any difference in Eclipse. How do I use that plugin? There are no instructions on that site.

Please suggest something. Thank you very much!

Comment: Maybe a naive question, but did you check your context menu? And maybe a new perspective is available?

Answer (score 4):

The Sonar-ESQL-Plugin is only a plugin for sonarQube. 
For a eclipse integration the plugin needs to support SonarLint, which it does not.
To analyse ESQL code you need to install SonarQube, add the ESQL-plugin to it and run the analysis using maven or SonarQube Scanner: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+Source+Code

BTW: The website you used to download the plugin, doesn't provide the latest version. Try to download it for github: https://github.com/EXXETA/sonar-esql-plugin